# How to provide parameter to docker run with "oc new-app" in OpenShift?

Tags: docker, openshift-origin

When I run some docker containers, I need to provide parameters on the command line (`docker run image some-parameters`). How can I provide the same parameters when using `oc new-app` in OpenShift Origin?

Answer (score 1):

The [`oc new-app` example](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/generated/oc_by_example_content.adoc#oc-new-app) includes:

```
# Create an application based on a template file, explicitly setting a parameter value
$ oc new-app --file=./example/myapp/template.json --param=MYSQL_USER=admin
```

The `--param` option can be useful here.

---

Note: The [`oc run` example](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/generated/oc_by_example_content.adoc#oc-run) include:

```
# Start a single instance of nginx, but overload the spec of the replication
# controller with a partial set of values parsed from JSON.
$ oc run nginx --image=nginx --overrides='{ "apiVersion": "v1", "spec": { ... } }'
```

That json can include a parameter section, as does [this one](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/0d899cf42bd12faa297e5a7c6e8b95af8a580017/test/extended/fixtures/incremental-auth-build.json#L110-L111) used by [`sti_incremental.go#L39`](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/0d899cf42bd12faa297e5a7c6e8b95af8a580017/test/extended/builds/sti_incremental.go#L39).

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, what is the difference between `oc new-app` and `oc run`?

Comment: @XiaoPeng I have edited the answer to include `oc new-app`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on `oc run -h`:

```
oc run NAME --image=image [--env="key=value"] [--port=port] [--replicas=replicas] [--dry-run=bool] [--overrides=inline-json] [--command] -- [COMMAND] [args...] [options]
```

For me the following worked:

```
oc run my_command --image='alpine'  --command -- telnet some_server 22
```